# Fullscreen FPS low on Ubuntu GNOME 16.10

Tags: amd-graphics, ubuntu-gnome, gpu-driver, fullscreen

Whenever I play games or watch videos even in the firefox webbrowser or whatsoever my FPS drop like with enabled V-Sync.

For example
500 fps windowed mode
60 fps fullscreen mode

Using no opensource drivers (AMD Radeon 8500m)